# Optimizing UPDATE of a large table in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a large table with 1.4B records. Everyday I have to update some records of this large table based on some condition in another table (smaller but not very small) by using UPDATE statement  like the following:

```
UPDATE my_large_table set a_field_that_needs_to_be_updated = 1 WHERE join_field IN (SELECT join_field FROM another_table where some_other_conditions
```

This takes sometimes more than 30 minutes which is our timeout value so the job will just be aborted.

1. One easy solution is to increase the timeout value but that's not the route I want to take.
2. Another optimization could be using join_field as distkey in both table schema but there is more common join use cases so another field is set as distkey.

So I am wondering if I can break this query into multiple partitioned queries. join_field is actually an alphanumeric hash value and I can just look at the first character of the field and run the statement in 36 smaller pieces (0 to 9 and A to Z) using LIKE. But I am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would say that chunking the queries as you mentioned would be your best bet. Ordinarily, the quickest thing to do would be to do this with a combination of `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` on conjunction with `ORDER BY` to define the chunks, but using really large ordered `OFFSET` values can be a performance issue unto itself (since it has to compute the whole order first, and then due the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`), especially given the number of records you have in the table.

However, since you stated that you already have them partitioned via a hash value that you can uniquely iterate over, I would simply go with that as the chunking mechanism -- it's built in, and should give you much smaller chunks to work with. You could consider subdividing those chunks further via the mechanism I mentioned earlier if they are still too large to perform well.

Note that you may need to have indexes on the hash column so it will be able to find them quickly, although from a pure *Postgres* perspective they may not be used if the query planner decides too many rows will need to be returned (and *Redshift* may have additional differences).

To optimize it further, you could consider multi-threading it to do multiple updates at once. I often use the [*GNU parallel*](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool for this, since it allows for quick and easy multithreading of shell commands. This could be used in conjunction with the *psql* client, which, near as I can tell, is supported in *Redshift*.

**Note:**

Ultimately, I think the best overall bet would be to have separate tables for each first-character of the hash value, each of which inherits from a master table. That makes it so that each table can be dealt with individually in an `UPDATE` without having to go through a large filtering operation first, etc., but you can still query all of the tables using the parent table (i.e. it shouldn't really impact existing `SELECT` statements).

However, that is certainly a larger undertaking that may not be feasible to do right now, and if you were to do such a thing, you'd want to verify with the query planner, etc. that it really is an improvement and that there are no *Redshift* specific reasons that this isn't a good idea (I'm speaking purely from a *Postgres* perspective).